# Progress in label

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

Use code for show downloading progress in percent

```
float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
        float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

        NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", (int)((progress/total)*100)];
        [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", percentage]];
 _label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323.43, 148.84, 42, 19)];
        [_label setText: percentage];
        _label.numberOfLines = 1;
        _label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        _label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        _label.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
        _label.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.view addSubview:_label];
```

If I use `_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];` progress label work correctly. But if I use `_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` numbers superimposed on each other

Why?

`_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];`
[image]

`_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` [image]

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding multiples labels with the method `[self.view addSubview: _label]` If you want to see that more visually use the Debug View Hierarchy when you are debugging. 
To solve the issue you can check if the _label is not nil and you will set only the text. See the code below:

```
    float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
    float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

    NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", ((progress / total) * 100)];

    if (!_label) {

        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323.43, 148.84, 42, 19)];

        _label.numberOfLines = 1;
        _label.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
        _label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        _label.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
        _labellabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
        _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self.view addSubview:_label];
   }

   _label.text = percentage;
```

Notice that you are trying to set the text before initialize it: `[_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", percentage]];` and if _label is nil the app crash in that point.
Try to avoid set the frame manually instead of that use auto layout.

Comment: Unlike Swift, invoking a method on `nil` doesn't crash in Objective-C; it just doesn't do anything and can lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be adding multiple labels `[self.view addSubview: _label]`. This code should only be executed once. With a black background you can only see the topmost label. With a clear background you can see them all

Answer (score 0):

I think, the Label have overlapped. So you can use "tag" value to remove the label and recreated it every time.

**Adding Tag**

```
_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323.43, 148.84, 42, 19)];  // after you will set the tag for the required Label.
_label.tag = 505;
```

**Remove and recreate the label**

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:505]removeFromSuperView]; // after you will create the Label
_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(323.43, 148.84, 42, 19)];
```